# How do I layer a dropdown menu over the slider revolution?

Tags: css, wordpress

I have an idx search bar above the slider revolution on my homepage. I would like the dropdown menu to layer above the slider images, not behind it. This is my website: http://btbowden-001-site11.htempurl.com/

Appreciate any help on this! Thanks!

Mindy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the slider parent container a lower `z-index` than the search bar parent container.

They currently have the same class names of `.wpb_column .vc_column_container .vc_col-sm-12`.

So give them unique class names if possible and give the search bar parent container `z-index: 2;` and the slider parent container `z-index: 1;`

The exact `z-index` number doesn't matter too much as long as the search bar one is a higher number.